# Python: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm tyring to test the Python Selenium and I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8tgRQ7DOzAbn9L7zDL8mLg/videos'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('style-scope ytd-grid-renderer')

for video in videos:
    title = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
    views = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
    when = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
    print(title,views,when)
```

And during run I have this error:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

It run until the line "videos = driver....."
Can you help me on fixing i on my side?

Answer (score 2):

When you trying to locate elements using class names you cannot use multiple class names which you are getting the error. You will have to provide just one.
In your code "style-scope" and "ytd-grid-renderer" are 2 different classes that are attached to your DOM tag. if you still want to identify using both the classes, you can use either of the below 2 ways.

css selector:

```
videos = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.style-scope.ytd-grid-renderer')
```

xpath:

```
 videos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='style-scope ytd-grid-renderer']")
```

Comment: Are you sure that `'.style-scope,.ytd-grid-renderer'` is valid syntax? Did you mean `'.style-scope.ytd-grid-renderer'`?

Comment: And it still have error after changing it:
 title = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: this should work. i don't see any issue with your xpath. can you try using find_element_by_id('video-title') instead of xpath or doing getAttribute('innerHTML') instead of text and check.

Comment: @JaSON Thanks for the correction. the comma is not supposed to be there. I have correct the code